# Hook shutdown script to shutting down sequnce

Tags: shutdown

Is it possible to hook some script to shutting down sequence for Linux?

To give you a bit more context processes of nodes of the cluster are started as processes from cluster -master. They are not running as services. However if someone restart a node and didn't stop the appropriate process manually, it causes a troubles because the node hasn't been stopped gracefully.

I would like to avoid this situation. Processes they don't run as services.

Comment: what's the parent-process of these processes? if this is a service itself, you can sigterm this service or the cgroup. if the processes are detached/nohup, can you identify them by their binary-name? is it possible to create a pidfile?

Answer (score 0):

I'd link a script that would shut down the nodes to /etc/rc6.d

It'll run on runlevel 6, that coresponds to shutdown sequence. Link name should be of format KXXName, where XX is a sequence number.

I'm assuming here that you have control over the nodes and you are able to wait for them to shut down gracefully.